# sync data from mongodb to elasticsearch via logstash

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash

I just want to sync the data from mongodb to elastic using logstash. Its working good, when any new record comes in mongodb, logstash pushes into elastic. But when I update any record in mongodb then it does not change into elasticsearch even when i delete it nothing happen . I want to make changes in the config file so that when any record updates or deleted in mongo it should reflect in elastic as well.

```
input {
mongodb {

    uri => 'mongodb://xxxxxx:32769/database'
    placeholder_db_dir =>'/usr/share/logstash/bin/opt/logstash-mongodb/'
    placeholder_db_name => 'logstash_sqlite.db'
    collection => 'tags'
}
}
filter {
mutate {
rename => { "_id" => "mongo_id" }
}
}
output {
    stdout {
            codec => rubydebug
    }
    elasticsearch {
            action => "index"
            index => "mongo_data"
            hosts => ["https://xxxxxxxx:8443"]
            ssl => true
  doc_as_upsert => true

   }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a use-case that the input was designed to support. The [documentation](https://github.com/phutchins/logstash-input-mongodb) states "This was designed for parsing logs that were written into mongodb. This means that it may not re-parse db entries that were changed and already parsed." For "may not" read "will not". The [code](https://github.com/phutchins/logstash-input-mongodb/blob/097cc9be8bb57754ec4006e174f0cb5cf3ff6b65/lib/logstash/inputs/mongodb.rb#L147) builds a cursor that finds documents with an id greater than the last id it read. It never looks for updates or deletions. Note also that the test is "greater than the last id" and the way it [initializes](https://github.com/phutchins/logstash-input-mongodb/blob/097cc9be8bb57754ec4006e174f0cb5cf3ff6b65/lib/logstash/inputs/mongodb.rb#L96) the last id means it never reads the first document in the collection.

Comment: So what will be the solution to manage updates ,adds and deletions ?

Comment: I do not think logstash can do that with any of the existing plugins.