# Logstash doesn't update the data when mongodb data gets updated

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have configured logstash in order to synchronize elasticsearch with mongodb.

This is my configuration that works properly:

```
input {
  mongodb {
        uri => '<my_mongo_db_uri>'
        placeholder_db_dir => '/opt/logstash-mongodb/'
        placeholder_db_name => '<my_placeholeder>.db'
        collection => '<my_mongo_db_collection>'
        batch_size => 5000
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["_id"]
  }
}

output {
        stdout {
                codec => rubydebug
        }

        elasticsearch {
                action => "index"
                index => "<my_index>"
                hosts => ["http://<my_elasticsearch_ip>:9200"]
        }
}
```

Now I would update it in order to automatically propagate in elasticsearch any mongo document modification.

Can anyone address me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [document_id](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-document_id) in the `logstash => output => elasticsearch` to update documents part.
Here is an example:

```
input {
  mongodb {
    uri => '<my_mongo_db_uri>'
    placeholder_db_dir => '/opt/logstash-mongodb/'
    placeholder_db_name => '<my_placeholeder>.db'
    collection => '<my_mongo_db_collection>'
    batch_size => 5000
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    rename => {"_id" => "id"}
  }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        index => "<my_index>"
        hosts => ["http://<my_elasticsearch_ip>:9200"]
        document_id => "%{id}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Musab, I have applied your suggestion but without success. After having changed data in Mongo, I don't see anything in Logstash trace and in Elasticsearch I don't find the modification.

Comment: Moreover if I add a new doc to Mongo, it is automatically propagated to Elasticsearch.

Comment: To clarify, with Logstash ALL data migrates from MongoDB to Elasticsearch, every time logstash is triggered, is that correct?

Comment: When Logstash starts ALL Mongo data are migrated to Elasticsearch. Once the the migration is done, if I add a doc in Mongo this is automatically migrated to Elasticsearch, BUT if I modify a doc property this change is NOT migrated to elasticsearch.

Comment: Maeby it is requested a particular Mongo DB configuration ?

Comment: From this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66550645/sync-data-from-mongodb-to-elasticsearch-via-logstash, it seems that mongo plugin is not able to detect the mongo doc changes. Is it correct?